# Have an after_request per endpoint in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

Is it possible to use an `after_request` for every route in my api?
My main goal would be to do something like this:

```
@blueprint.route('/endpoint', methods=['GET'])
@after_request_handler(valid_status_codes=[200, 404])
def endpoint():
    return {"hello": "world"}, 200
```

Then in the after_request_handler I would check if the status_code of the response I receive is in the `valid_status_codes` list I passed as argument and therefore know if the request was successful or not.
Something like this:

```
def after_request_handler(valid_status_codes, response):
    if response.status_code in valid_status_codes:
        # Send request was successful metric event
    else:
        # Send request was unsuccessful metric event
    return response
```

With this I want to have metrics of every endpoint in my api and know if they start to fail for some reason. Maybe there is some library or an easier way to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just use `errorhandler` + `after_request`:

```
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/good')
def good():
    return 'ok'


@app.route('/bad')
def bad():
    raise Exception('bad route')


@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def error(e):
    # do here all what you need with errors
    if isinstance(e, HTTPException):
        print('response code %s' % e.code)
    else:
        print('undefined error %s' % str(e))
    raise e


@app.after_request
def log(response):
    # do here all what you need with success responses
    print('good response %s' % response.status_code)
    return response
```

run server and open `/`, `/bad`, `/good`:

```
response code 404
undefined error bad route
good response 200
```

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed, by passing your handler to `app.after_request()`.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.after_request(after_request_handler)
app.run()
```

Your handler must take and return a Response object. I don't believe it can take any other parameters as you have no control over how the handler is called.

From https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.Flask.after_request

> This is available on both app and blueprint objects. When used on an app, this executes after every request. When used on a blueprint, this executes after every request that the blueprint handles. To register with a blueprint and execute after every request, use Blueprint.after_app_request().